# Why does replacing a JToken not update the token itself?

Tags: c#, json.net

If I select a `JToken` from a `JObject`, when I replace that `JToken` why does it not update even though the `JObject` does?

Take this code as an example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace TestingSolution
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private const string TestJson = 
@"{
    ""name"": ""Test Json"",
    ""values"": {
        ""SomeValue"": ""12345""
    }
}";
        public static void Main()
        {
            JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(TestJson);
            JToken values = parsedJson.SelectToken("values");

            values.Replace(JToken.Parse("{\"SomeValue2\": \"98765\"}"));

            Console.WriteLine("===== parsedJson =====");
            Console.WriteLine(parsedJson.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("\n======= values =======");
            Console.WriteLine(values.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When it runs, it will output the following:

```
===== parsedJson =====
{
  "name": "Test Json",
  "values": {
    "SomeValue2": "98765"
  }
}

======= values =======
{
  "SomeValue": "12345"
}
```

Why does the `values` object have the old data in it?

Using `Newtonsoft.Json` version `13.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Because is is designed so. As said in the docs [`JToken.Replace`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Replace.htm):

> Replaces this token with the specified token.

i.e. the whole token is replaced with a new one in the parent container leaving the token "value" intact. Note that token will change though - properties like `Path`, `Parent`, `Root` will change to corresponding new values.